# Playing mp3 file without jumping to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a rails app in which a user can upload an mp3 file and then play/delete it. However, I am trying to make it so that when the user pushes the play button, the mp3 file is played without jumping to another page. In my index.html.erb file, I have the following code:

```
<% @audio.each do |audio| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= audio.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Play", audio.attachment_url, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
```

I know that I am currently linking my play button to the attachment url, but I don't know how to make it so that it simply plays on the current page. Please help

Comment: Which `gem` you are using to upload the audio file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out the audio tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question of

> make it so that when the user pushes the play button, the mp3 file is played without jumping to another page ... I don't know how to make it so that it simply plays on the current page.

do this ...

```
$(".btn.btn-primary").on 'click', (event)->
  event.preventDefault()
```